# Gemfire Pdx Serialization Put All

Tags: gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire

Is it normal that a client application took a longer time to insert data into GemFire Cluster for the first time? For example, my client application took around 4 seconds to insert GemFire Cluster successfully. However , the subsequent insert only took around 1 second. May i know what is the reason behind it?

[image: Client Application Log File]

```
@Configuration
@EnablePool(name = "sgpool", socketBufferSize = 1000000, prSingleHopEnabled = true, idleTimeout = 10000)
public class RegionConfiguration {

@Bean("People")
public ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, Person> customersRegion(GemFireCache gemfireCache) {
    ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, Person> customersRegion = new ClientRegionFactoryBean<>();
    customersRegion.setCache(gemfireCache);
    customersRegion.setClose(false);
    customersRegion.setPoolName("sgpool");
    customersRegion.setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY);
    return customersRegion;
  }
}

@ClientCacheApplication
@EnablePdx
@Service
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses = PersonRepository.class)
@Import(RegionConfiguration.class)
public class PersonDataAccess {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("People")
private Region<String, Person> peopleRegion;

@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    peopleRegion.registerInterestForAllKeys();
}

public void saveAll(Iterable<Person> iteratorList) {
    personRepository.saveAll(iteratorList);
 }
}

@Service
@EnableScheduling
@Log4j2
public class PersonService {

@Autowired
public PersonDataAccess personDataAccess;

private Person createPerson(String ic, int age) {
    return new Person(ic, "Jack - " + age, "Kay - " + age, LocalDate.of(2000, 12, 10), age, 2,
            new Address("Jack Wonderful Land 12", "Wonderful Land", "Wonderful 101221"), "11111", "22222", "33333",
            "Dream", "Space");
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 5000)
public void testSaveRecord() {
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 30000; counter++) {
        personList.add(createPerson("S2011" + counter, counter));
    }
    log.info("start saving person");
    personDataAccess.saveAll(personList);
    log.info("Complete saving all the message");
}
}
```

GemFire Configuration:

1. Using PDX Serialization
2. 1 Locator and Cache Server (GemFire 9.10.5
3. Partition Region
4. Client Application (Using Spring Data GemFire 2.3.4)

Thank you so much

Comment: I think the “caching PDX type” gives it away. Maybe there is a cache synchronisation check between client cache PDX types registry and server cache PDX types registry and if there’s a mismatch then there is a PDX cache registry mechanism sync....

Comment: I don't know is it due to synchronization check for pdx type between client and server. However, i did not use persistent region or store pdx in the GemFire Server.  The GemFire Server was having "fresh start" before i run the client application

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the 1st time there’s a PDX cache register process going on between client and server kind of like

[client server event distribution](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/14/developing/events/how_client_server_distribution_works.html)

The register process does not need to happen 2nd time because it’s now setup.

The PDX registration process is explained more [here](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/19/developing/data_serialization/PDX_Serialization_Features.html) where it says: Geode maintains a central registry of the PDX domain object metadata.

There must be a way to get the region setup done before your 1st insert, so that each insert is the same.

Maybe [this could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009082/spring-boot-data-geode-put-to-region-causing-duplicate-lower-case-pdx-elements)

Comment: I am using Spring Data GemFire's MappingPdxSerializer, As a result, i don't need to implements the PDX serialization. I created a ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, Person> customersRegion bean. I also thinking whether it is PDX registration process. However, i don't know how to start the process earlier.

Comment: Try `@Resource
 private Region<String, String> myRegion;`

Comment: I tried @Resource(name = "People") private Region<String, Person> peopleRegion; .. still the same result.